# Search FB Messenger Message for Specific Word in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, preg-match, chatbot, messenger

So I'm trying to create a Facebook Messenger Chatbot, a very simple one. I have it working with a hardcoded response, but I want it to be able to read the senders message and respond in a specific way if it finds that word - like how chatbots should. I' trying to do so by using `preg_match()` but when I use my current code, the bot doesn't reply at all. Here's my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Webhook for Facebook Messenger Bot
 */
$access_token = "{mytoken}";
$verify_token = "{mytoken2}";

$hub_verify_token = null;
if (isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {
    $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    $hub_verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
}
if ($hub_verify_token == $verify_token) {
    echo $challenge;
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

// perform a case-Insensitive search for the word "time"
if (preg_match('[hi|hello|sup]', $message)) {
    $answer = "Hiya!";
}
else {
    $answer = "IDK.";
}

// send the response back to sender
// 'text': 'Hiya!'

$jsonData = "{
    'recipient': {
        'id': $sender
    },
    'message': {
        'text': $answer
    }
}";

// initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=$access_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
if (!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])) {
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: That is not how preg_match works

Comment: @WizKid funny enough, PHP allows brackets as delimiters ...

Comment: First, insert some debug lines and look at the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know whether you actually receive messages from the Messenger Platform? Your webhook verification ends in an `echo`, where in fact you need to respond to the platform with a status code `200`. You can also check your Facebook Apps dashboard to figure out whether your webhook is verified and being sent messages.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup

Once you know that your webhook is verified and you are receiving messages, start with a fixed reply and then work towards dynamic responses. As @Toto suggested, adding logging will be very helpful to debug your code.